# Regex with repeated characters and length in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-group

I have a regex where I need to match the letter part in a capture.  The letters can be 1-3 characters in length and must be the same letter.  No ABC, but A, AA, or AAA works, followed by a number.  I can only match A1 currently, not AA1.  I am using .NET for the Regex.

```
^(?<pool>([A-Z])\1{0,2})(?<number>(100)|[1-9]\d?)$

A1
AA2
AAA3
B5
CC7
```

Comment: could you add the programming language you are using?

Comment: Like [This](https://regex101.com/r/C5rLiv/2)?

Comment: I hope I am not all too late to the party. :) – wp78de 1 hour ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small supplement and correction to Allan's neat answer:

The 3rd pattern does not match correctly in .NET's regex engine because the backreference `\2` has to be numbered differently than in the shown PCRE pattern (using regex101).

Instead of `\2` it needs to be `\1`:

```
^(?<pool>([A-Z])\1{0,2})(?<number>(100|[1-9]\d?))$
```

This [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M2aZ2r) demonstrates the problem: instead of ~300 test-cases I've generated only the first 100 (from A1-A100) are matched.

You can check this yourself using [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester), a .NET regex tester.

Why? There is a subtle difference between how named capturing groups mixed with regular capture groups are referenced in .NET regex and PCRE, e.g. in PHP.

At a glance it works the same way:

> Captures that use parentheses are numbered automatically from left to
>   right based on the order of the opening parentheses in the regular
>   expression, starting from one**. The capture that is numbered zero is
>   the text matched by the entire regular expression pattern.

Ref. [MSDN: Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named_matched_subexpression)

So, while

> most flavors number both named and unnamed capturing groups by
>   counting their opening parentheses from left to right. Adding a named
>   capturing group to an existing regex still upsets the numbers of the
>   unnamed groups

In .NET, however,

> unnamed capturing groups are
>   assigned numbers first, counting their opening parentheses from left
>   to right, skipping all named groups. After that, named groups are
>   assigned the numbers that follow by counting the opening parentheses
>   of the named groups from left to right.

This is actually explained on the very same page on [regular-expressions.info/named.html](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) linked in the answer.

A simple example:

To match `1a1` in .NET you could use

```
(?<named>(\d)a)\1
```

To match in a similar way in PHP you would have to use \2 in instead

```
(?<named>(\d)a)\2
```

The moral:

> Mixing named and numbered capturing groups is not recommended because
>   flavors are inconsistent in how the groups are numbered.

BTW:

I've prepared this pattern [`\b(?<pool>([A-Z])\1{0,2})(?<number>(\d{1,2}(?!\d)|100))\b`](https://regex101.com/r/W7A46g/1) but then shifted the attention to the difference outlined above. You can also play with `\1` vs `\2` on the linked demo.

Answer (score 5):

Would the following regex work for you?

```
\b(([A-Z])\2{0,2}(?:100|[1-9]\d?))\b
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/IvvEBC/3/)

It does accept: `A1 AA2 AAA3 B5 CC7` and does not match `AAAA4` or `ABC123`

If you want to use **Named Capturing Groups and Backreferences** to them then you can change your regex into:

```
^(?<pool>([A-Z]))\k<pool>{0,2}(?<number>(100|[1-9]\d?))$
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/IvvEBC/4/)

Let me know if it works for you, also have a look at:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Last but not least, if you want the named capturing group `<pool>` to match and capture `A`, `AA` or `AAA` you can use:

```
^(?<pool>([A-Z])\2{0,2})(?<number>(100|[1-9]\d?))$
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/IvvEBC/5/)

With only named Capturing Groups:

```
^(?<pool>(?<letter>[A-Z])\k<letter>{0,2})(?<number>(100|[1-9]\d?))$
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/IvvEBC/6/)

Comment: AA does not match <pool>, just A

Comment: @MikeFlynn: let me fix this for you

Comment: @MikeFlynn: what about the latest regex?

Comment: @Allan nice. The 3rd pattern however needs `\1` instead as backreference. See my answer.

Comment: This answer works on the onlin tester, but not in .NET for some reason.  Any clue why?